# How to use `ansible-vault` `--output` to write the encrypted content to a file?

Tags: ansible, command-line-interface, ansible-vault

I'm using `ansible-vault` 2.10.5. According to the `encrypt_string` documentation, I can use [`--output` to save the encrypted result](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-vault.html#cmdoption-ansible-vault-encrypt-string-output). The doc says:

> --output <OUTPUT_FILE>
>
> output file name for encrypt or decrypt; use - for stdout

But I tried several commands and **the result seemed to always be printed to the console**. For example:

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-id test@prompt --name my_var --output encrypted.txt my_value
```

I got the following output printed on the console:

```
New vault password (test): 
Confirm new vault password (test): 
my_var: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;test
          66343062376436373531313033623237393231663930383936306662393164653733636161653630
          6636653035306339363065623438353338646533656639620a376365376136343232376561666266
          62313936343766343333333065363634663961643234323734613135383763656536656437393431
          3238306436313437320a663131653164366133356530663732633334366136306636663766353331
          6635
Encryption successful
```

**So what is the correct way of using `--output` option to save the encrypted content to a local file?**

Comment: Seems like a bug, it doesn't work for my Ansible 2.9.16

Comment: Update, works only this way: `ansible-vault encrypt_string >~/test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather put the target content to be encrypted in a file and use `ansible-vault encrypt secretfile` and it will enctypt the file in place.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug, here's the relevant record in the issue tracker: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/75101.